# I'm an absolute beginner in swift. I don't what's wrong with the output of my code, This is based on mutating methods

Tags: swift, xcode

A Post struct has been created for you below, representing a generic social media post. Add a mutating method on Post called like that will increment likes by one. Then create an instance of Post and call like() on it. Print out the likes property before and after calling the method to see whether or not the value was incremented.

```
struct Post {
    var message: String
    var likes: Int=0
    var numberOfComments: Int

    mutating func like(){
        likes=likes+1
    }

}var call=Post()
print(call.like)
```

error: 5. Exercise - Methods.xcplaygroundpage:34:2: error: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
}var call=Post()
 ^
 ;

Comment: "consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'" you have the answer to your problem right in front of you. Learning to read compiler error messages is one important step in learning to write code.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing 2 lines of code in a single line without separating them with a semicolon(`;`).

```
}var call=Post()
```

**Solution:** Either separate them with semicolon(`;`) or write them in separate lines, i.e.

```
struct Post {
    var message: String
    var likes: Int=0
    var numberOfComments: Int

    mutating func like(){
        likes=likes+1
    }
}

var call = Post(message: "", likes: 0, numberOfComments: 0)  //here.....
print(call.likes)
call.like()
```

Also, the `var call = Post()` won't work. No such `init` exist for this `struct`. `struct Post` only accepts a parameterized `init`.

Comment: I'd also suggest that it should be `call.likes`, otherwise they will be printing the function reference ;)